# Customized cleveref

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, cleveref

How can I customize the `cleveref` package such that when I type

```
\begin{equation}
A = B
\label{eqn:test}
\end{equation}

\cref{eqn:test}
```

then the output is

Eq. (1)

where Eq. is black and (1) is blue with hyperlink?

Comment: With which options do you load the `cleveref` package? For sure, don't specify the `nameinlink` option if you don't want the objects' names included in the hyperlinks.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 3):

For those that like colourful links etc. ;-)

Label formats for individual counter types can be changed with `\creflabelformat{counter type}{#2Y#3}` where Y stands for some formatting code with should contain the parameter `#1`

`#2` and `#3` are used by the hyperanchors and must appear in this order -- do not change or remove this!

As can be detected from the screen shot the cross-reference format for the table counter is not affected by this.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{cleveref}

\creflabelformat{equation}{#2{\color{blue}(#1)}#3}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
A = B
\label{eqn:test}
\end{equation}
\begin{table}
\caption{Foo} \label{foolabel}
\end{table}
\clearpage

\cref{eqn:test} or \Cref{eqn:test} but \cref{foolabel}\dots
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It's probably a good idea to pass the options `colorlinks=true` and `linkcolor=blue` directly to the `hyperref` package.

Comment: @Mico: That's what I had in mind, but it would change any links then, wouldn't it? I suspect that the table reference is blue too then...

Comment: Indeed, the `linkcolor` option pertains to all cross-references, not just to cross-references to equations. But then, I certainly believe it's good practice to use only one color for all cross-references n a document -- unless one is going for either a "holiday card" or a "ransom note" look...

Comment: @Mico: I can do this ... but the customer's always right, isn't he/she? ;-)

Comment: Of course the customer's always right. :-) For the case at hand, though, I don't think the customer expressed any particular views on what the *other* hyperlinks should like. So it's up to you to explore how much creative freedom there may be... :-)

Comment: @Mico: Well, the customer asked for the equation reference, and that's he just got ... anything else will cost extra fee ;-)